# Matching variable names

Tags: r

I have a dataset that currently look like this:

```
Actor1    Actor2
1           2
1           4
2           5
1           3
2           6
4           5
2           7
3           7
```

And another dataset that I have identifies what each of the numbers mean. Something like this:

```
ID    Label
1     Walmart
2     Apple
3     Microsoft
4     Vodafone
5     BMW
6     Berkshire Hathaway
7     Bank of America
```

I need to use the second dataset to identify who the Actors are in the first dataset and I want my final dataset to look like:

```
Actor1     Actor2
Walmart     Apple
Walmart    Vodafone
Apple       BMW
.
.
.
```

and so on. I initially used ifelse function and did it manually but it is taking too long. And then I tried the merge function by creating three data files (file 1: Actor 1; file 2: Actor 2; file 3: ID and Names). But the order is messed up between Actor1 and Actor2 column.

It feels like this should be straightforward to do but I am confused. Any good ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A base R approach

```
d <- with(df2, setNames(ID, Label))
list2DF(Map(function(x, y) names(d)[match(x, y)], df1, list(d)))
```

gives

```
     Actor1             Actor2
1   Walmart              Apple
2   Walmart           Vodafone
3     Apple                BMW
4   Walmart          Microsoft
5     Apple Berkshire Hathaway
6  Vodafone                BMW
7     Apple    Bank of America
8 Microsoft    Bank of America
```

---

A much shorter one (thank @akrun's comment)

```
df1[] <- df2$Label[as.matrix(df1)]
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df1)
structure(list(Actor1 = c("Walmart", "Walmart", "Apple", "Walmart",
"Apple", "Vodafone", "Apple", "Microsoft"), Actor2 = c("Apple",
"Vodafone", "BMW", "Microsoft", "Berkshire Hathaway", "BMW",
"Bank of America", "Bank of America")), row.names = c(NA, -8L
), class = "data.frame")

> dput(df2)
structure(list(ID = 1:7, Label = c("Walmart", "Apple", "Microsoft", 
"Vodafone", "BMW", "Berkshire Hathaway", "Bank of America")), class = "data.frame", row.names = 
c(NA,
-7L))
```

Comment: @akrun Awesome solution!

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Using `factor` is one of the options in base `R`

```
cbind.data.frame(lapply( df1, function(x) factor(x, levels = df2$ID, labels = df2$Label)))

#     Actor1             Actor2
#1   Walmart              Apple
#2   Walmart           Vodafone
#3     Apple                BMW
#4   Walmart          Microsoft
#5     Apple Berkshire Hathaway
#6  Vodafone                BMW
#7     Apple    Bank of America
#8 Microsoft    Bank of America
```

**Data:**

```
df1 <- structure(list(Actor1 = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L), Actor2 = c(2L, 
4L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 7L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))

df2 <- structure(list(ID = 1:7, Label = c("Walmart", "Apple", "Microsoft", 
"Vodafone", "BMW", "Berkshire Hathaway", "Bank of America")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```